# Is there a way to know whether the OS supports dark mode in a web page? (by JavaScript, CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, darkmode

Is there anything like `CSS.supports('dark-mode')` ?

I tried this:

```
try {

  if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
      // dark mode
  }

} catch (e) {
  alert('do not support dark mode');
}
```

But the `alert` would never run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert` doesn't run because there is nothing in your try-block that throws an error. The if-condition returns true/false, which means you need a simple if/else-statement:

```js
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
   // dark mode
} else {
  // light mode
}
```

If you need to detect if the media query string `prefers-color-scheme` is supported by the browser, then you may have to explicitly check for both light and dark:

```js
function isPreferredColorSchemeSupported() {
  return (
    window.matchMedia &&
    (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches ||
      window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)
  );
}
```

If `false` is returned, then you know that the browser didn't match the `light` or the `dark` media query, from which you can infer that the browser didn't understand the media query.

Comment: Beat me by seconds, but yea that's not what try/catch is for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it doesn't throw an error when it doesn't match.

```
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
      // dark mode
  } else { alert('do not support dark mode'); }
```